# Use htaccess and mod_rewrite to conditionally make url segment uppercase

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite my URL's to do the following:

If the last segment of the URL starts with a 'p' followed by a number, that P should be uppercase.

So: `domain.com/path/to/something/p112` should become `domain.com/path/to/something/P112`, but `domain.com/p123/something/else` should NOT become `domain.com/P123/something/else`

I know how to simply replace characters, but I'm not sure how to limit this to the last segment, and only apply if it matches a certain pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)p(.*)$ /$1P$2 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/p(\d+/?)$ /$1/P$2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

- `.+` is greedy so it will match longest match before matching last `/`.
- `\d+` will match 1 or more digits.

Comment: Turns out this also rewrites `domain.com/brand/power` to `../brand/Power`. Can I modify it so that it only rewrites the last segment if the pattern is `p<1 or more digits>`?